# Android Layouts - ImageView inside ScrollView - space before Image

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and still learning the lingo of how things are done and have a question about layouts.

[image: Trying to Achieve]

What I am getting (Extra space at the top, black background):

[image: What I am getting]

I would like to have a layout with a top bar, containing some buttons; a middle, which is scrollable; and a bottom bar, which also contains buttons. I've currently only implemented part of the layout, but I have a question on putting an ImageView inside a ScrollView.

Here is my XML for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Previous" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnCurrent"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnPrevious"
 android:text="Current" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnCurrent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/childOfScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   

        >
        <com.example.touch.TouchImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:contentDescription="none"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        />
   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/btnExtra"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
     android:text="Extra"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I am setting the Image dynamically with a URL, like such:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
currentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCurrent);
currentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String address = ImageAddress.getImageAddress(0);
        Bitmap bm = getImageBitmap(address); //
        image.setImageBitmap(bm); // where 
    }
});

// get image bitmap later in my code
private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        URL aURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e("Problem", "Error getting bitmap", e);
   }
   return bm;
}
```

To summarize quickly, why is it that I am getting all this extra lead space (the black background) at top (and bottom)?

**Update**

[image: Updated picture of layout]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnCurrent"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Current" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >

    <com.example.touch.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="none"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"  />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnExtra"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Extra"
     />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="button2" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It turns out that this is an artifact of the emulator, on actual devices, the display is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1， the top area is the actionbar, to hide it you can use NoActionBar theme or call 
    `getActionBar().hide();`

Update

2, you can use LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="button2" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:contentDescription="none"
        android:background="#000000"
         />
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="button2" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        mDownloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
        mDownloadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    private Button mDownloadButton;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    private final String ADDRESS =
        "http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14700000/Beautifull-cat-cats-14749885-500-375.jpg";
    private static Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Problem", "Error getting bitmap", e);
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new FetchBitmapTask().execute(ADDRESS);
    }

    private class FetchBitmapTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               }
           });
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            return getImageBitmap(strings[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the extra information regarding the layout on what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm still getting a large space at the top. (see update above)

Comment: for TouchImageView, please have a try to use`android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Changed, but still the same problem.

Comment: The background of the TouchImageView is black, the background of scrollview should be white, so In my opinion, the issue should be in your TouchImageView code. Please use ImageView instead of TouchImageView to have a test.

Comment: I changed it to regular ImageView and it still looks the same

Comment: It turns out that this is an artifact of the emulator, on actual devices, the display is correct.

Answer (score 15):

To adjust ImageView bounds to image size include:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

This will remove the margins created around the image.

Comment: I had the same issue and this corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the black area is maybe the background showing, and the picture is just centred strangely.

Maybe you could try changing the layout_marginTop in the TouchImageView to use dp instead of sp. It seems like from what I've read sp is supposed to be used mainly for text.

So something like:

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Comment: Didn't work, also, I removed the marginTop attribute all together and it still looks the same.

Comment: It turns out that this is an artifact of the emulator, on actual devices, the display is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Nick is right. You should use dp or dip for margins. Use sp for android:textSize

A suggestion to use LinearLayout would be better from how it looks now. Try the following. :)

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnCurrent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/childOfScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    >
    <com.example.touch.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="none"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Didn't work, also, I removed the marginTop attribute all together and it still looks the same.

Comment: I see the possible cause here.. You are setting the bitmap dynamically after the layout is drawn. Try building the scrollview dynamically instead, I have not got time to test it out but hope it steers you the right direction. Cheers.

Comment: It turns out that this is an artifact of the emulator, on actual devices, the display is correct.