# Horizontal ScrollView not work in android

Tags: android, imageview, horizontalscrollview

i want to make a Horizontal ScrollView but it show only 1 image and other images is hide but when is vertical is work good. i want it show in Horizontal and not hide. this is my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/ivgallery"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
    android:id="@+id/ivupload"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearmain"/>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my java code :

```
Bitmap bitmap = PhotoLoader.init().from(photopath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
imageView.setMaxWidth(250);
imageView.setMaxHeight(250);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use **[HorizontalScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)**

**HorizontalScrollView** only supports horizontal scrolling.For vertical scrolling, use either **ScrollView** or **ListView**.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing your scrollview child means LinearLayout
in that not anything

So please refer this link
`[Link][1]`[Link](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521958/android-layouts-imageview-inside-scrollview-space-before-image)

Comment: `LINK` is invalid

Comment: yes link is invalid but this is work i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521958/android-layouts-imageview-inside-scrollview-space-before-image

Answer (score 1):

for horizontal scroll you will have to use HorizontalScrollView

so replace this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</ScrollView>
```

with

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your scrollable content into scroll view

favorite
i want to make a Horizontal ScrollView but it show only 1 image and other images is hide but when is vertical is work good. i want it show in Horizontal and not hide. this is my xml code :

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearmain">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/ivgallery"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
    android:id="@+id/ivupload"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i put my scrollable content into scroll view but crashed app

Answer (score 0):

can you try this, change your element horizontal scrollview :

```
            <package_name.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/hlvCustomList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/add_image"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />
```

in your horizontal element, this is key of :

```
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

hope this will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `NestedScrollView` instead of scroll View 
and enter add `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to your RecyclerView in java